# MVC Application Expiring Application Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code in my `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddIdentity<MasterUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
{
    config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Authentication/Login");
    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/Authentication/Login");
    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Authentication/Login");
    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(36500);
    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
})
.AddUserManager<MasterUserIdentityManager>()
.AddUserStore<MasterUserIdentityClaimStore>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MasterDatabaseContext>();
```

The `ExpireTimeSpan` is set to 100 years while the `SlidingExpiration` is set to true but the application signs out the authenticated user after about 35 minutes, even when they  are active. It is as if these settings are not applied for some reason.

Comment: Do your users have a value in `SecurityStamp` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you may need to set `SecurityStampValidationInterval` too

```
config.SecurityStampValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(36500);;
```